# Basic: Are there apps (iOS/Android) that are capable of pooling/collecting data from various other apps?

Tags: android, ios

In this situation, we have say, three apps. These three apps collect specific data for whatever reason (about X, Y, and Z), all of which are in the same format. Is it possible to then develop a fourth app, which is able to take the information in the databases from each of these apps and pool it all in one place?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know IOS but In Android it is possible. Android is defined with a concept called Content Providers.

In theory, it is possible to define Apps that encapsulate content providers  for different kind of contents (let's say your X, Y and Z apps) and then be queried by another apps.

In practice this is the common way to retrieve information about user contacts in the device. Despite of that it is not a common use for other features.

This is the docs about Content Providers:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html?hl=es-419